# 409 error while accessing static resources on Stack Overflow (cdn.sstatic.net)

Tags: support, cdn

My browser window looks as follows:

[image: 1]

I have figured out that the problem is came from static resource URLs:

[image: 2]

There is no problem when using public web proxies (like hide.me), so I think it is on a ISP's side.

Any ideas of how to avoid it on my machine? Thanks.

Comment: DNS resolution isn't working for you, so... change what DNS servers you use?

Comment: I have no special DNS servers setup (obtained automatically). Can I do something to fix that?

Comment: You should be able to configure them - there are a few open ones (opendns or google dns servers, for example). How to configure depends on your OS, so look for a guide online for yours.

Comment: It could also be a local issue - so first try flushing your local DNS cache (again - look for your OS instructions online). Second thing to do - raise this with your ISP - they might have a bad DNS server or a bad cache.

Comment: Trying to change DNS servers manually leads to no access for all sites at all. Flushing DNS doesn't work too. I think the problem is on a ISP side. Are there any other options that I can try by myself?

Comment: If you do think it is with the ISP, that's who you need to talk to. You might manage with a VPN (to bypass the ISP filtering/servers), but if the issue is with their DNS, that might not help.